# Identify monospace font from picture

Tags: font-identification

I'd like to identify the font used in this:

[image: sample]

I tried searching it in [what the font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), [identifont](http://www.identifont.com) and [fonts by sight](http://www.fonts.com/id/by-sight), to no luck. If anyone knows the name or any other services I could try, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you should search in pages with rankings of the best monospaced fonts or in pages of digital foundries to see what the y have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Hermit https://pcaro.es/p/hermit/

It is a great open source font made for programming!

Comment: Thanks, it is great indeed! I was hoping it was open source!